# influence of device upon another device from power supply

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose I have a power supply like an ATX computer power supply (which outputs a pretty stable voltage). Now, assume that I an a friend both connect some electronic devices (in parallel) to this power supply with electric wires,  an do electronic experiments (the two devices are not close one to the other, and are isolated in order not to radiate and influence directly one the other. Furthermore, I assume that the devices involve electrical oscillations, transistors, amplifiers etc.). To what extent do the experiments performed by my friend influence my experiments through the electric wires and the power supply ?

Comment: You're thinking about it weirdly - wires don't conduct only useful power, but _all_ power you put through them!

Comment: I'm surprised of how prompt are persons to downvote threads in this forum. This contrasts with other stack exchange forums I'm used with.

Comment: @Dzarda. Thank you for your comment, but I don't see to what part of the question it answers. I have edited again the question and modified some details, hoping  to make it clearer.

Comment: What's the nature of the experiments?

Comment: @Nick Alexeev. I am trying to fund a small laboratory to realize some project, so this is not well defined. I have to work with very weak emissions in the range 0-15GHz, in the near field, to amplify them, to interact with them etc. I don't know the frequencies of these emissions, but I suspect they are about 10GHz (in this case, I guess that the impedance of the electric wires is sufficient to isolate one experimenter from the other, but I'm not so sure).

Comment: Can the persons who put this thread "on hold" clarify what is unclear in this question ? is it my English that is too bad ? is this question too elementary ? or is it that this forum does not allow general questions, and impose to describe how much voltage is applied to such and such electrode ? As a professional mathematician, I am used with the fact that any question can be given an answer, which should receive exactly the same level of generality and fuzziness as the question. This is why I think that Peter Haußmann has answered very well.

Answer (score 4):

Though providing a "pretty stable" voltage, any real power supply has a finite internal resistance causing a voltage drop dependent on the load current. Now, let's assume one of your devices only switches between "drawing some constant current" and "drawing no current". The voltage drop over the power supply's internal resistance causes the power supply's voltage output to be not constant anymore. Neglecting capacitive and inductive behaviour of the wires and devices, one would observe a square wave added to the DC supply voltage. Most power supplies use an output voltage control circuit to maintain the desired output voltage at any load current. However, such control circuits require some time to adapt to changing load currents.

In your case, the wires' inductive behaviour and the capacitors used in your device act as a low pass filter, attenuating the undesired AC components of your power supply's output voltage to some extent. However, even with further filtering, the supply voltage at your device's terminals will still contain AC components. It depends on your application whether this is acceptable.

In addition to these load caused effects, rectifiers' and switching voltage converters' in your PSU deliver a not-so-constant voltage to begin with. Therefore, highly precise measurement systems can be supplied by a battery in order to avoid spoiling measurement results.